# How do I concatenate data from multiple columns on one sheet into a single column on another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange, concatenate

I need to take separate columns containing first and last names on one spreadsheet, and combine them into a single column on a different sheet. Right now my formula is

```
=CONCATENATE(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "A1:A3"), " ", IMPORTRANGE("URL", "B1:B3"))
```

What I would want is to get a single column of

```
First1 Last1  
First2 Last2  
First3 Last3
```

But instead I am getting

```
First1First2First3 Last1Last2Last3
```

Because the second argument in the `IMPORTRANGE` function is a string, I can't just direct it to one cell and then drag the function over multiple cells like I normally would when concatenating. Is there a way to accomplish what I want without copying multiple data sets into one spreadsheet and working from there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with an `arrayformula` as follows:

```
=arrayformula(importrange("URL", "A1:A3") & " " & importrange("URL", "B1:B3"))
```

The inner part describes what should be done within one row; the `arrayformula` then says "do it for every row".

Comment: Thank you, this was great.  Although, it appears as though `ARRAYFORMULA` was only part of the fix.  When I added the `ARRAYFORMULA` to the outside of my formula I got the same formatting as before.  However, when I removed the `CONCATENATE` and replaced it with the `&`s it formatted properly.

Comment: Yes, binary concatenation `&` is important here; `concatenate` just  puts everything it's given together.